# What are all metrics than can be used in compiling tf.keras models?

Tags: python, metrics, tf.keras

To compile a tf.keras model one would go:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer='sgd',#'adam', or what not
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
    metrics=['accuracy','mae']
)
```

What are the other metrics that can be used as the parameter value for 'metrics'? I fruitlessly tried to look for them in [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/MeanAbsoluteError). I'm looking for the entire list.

Edit: I know one could use explicit form. e.g.

```
metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()] #instead of "mae"
```

but the short tags are more useful later for for plotting:

```
lossplot = df.plot(y="mae", title="Loss vs Epochs", legend=False)
lossplot.set(xLabel="Epochs", yLabel="Loss")
```

Answer (score 2):

From Keras [Model training APIs](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) page:

> **metrics**: List of metrics to be evaluated by the model during training
> and testing. Each of this can be a string (name of a built-in
> function), function or a tf.keras.metrics.Metric instance.[...]

and from Keras [Metrics](https://keras.io/api/metrics/#usage-with-compile-amp-fit) page:

> All built-in metrics may also be passed via their string identifier
> (in this case, default constructor argument values are used, including
> a default metric name)

Now you can find the entire list of build-in metrics in the [documentation link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics#functions_2) you found under the section Functions. It's basically the function name as string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Metrics` instead from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics

for example:

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])
```

from documentation:

> When you pass the strings 'accuracy' or 'acc', we convert this to one
> of tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy,
> tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy,
> tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy based on the shapes of the
> targets and of the model output.

and there is a possible list about all convert:
[What are all the valid strings I can use with keras.model.compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73422130/what-are-all-the-valid-strings-i-can-use-with-keras-model-compile)