# What are all the valid strings I can use with keras.model.compile?

Tags: python, keras

What strings are valid metrics with `keras.model.compile`?

The following works,

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse', metrics=['acc'])
```

but this does not work,

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse', metrics=['recall', 'precision'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check method to check **metrices**. Check docstring for details

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See [keras source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/6dd087ab73b09e449144ff17450cc14f981b9ac2/keras/metrics.py), the list of metrics is

- accuracy
- binary_accuracy
- categorical_accuracy
- sparse_categorical_accuracy
- top_k_categorical_accuracy
- sparse_top_k_categorical_accuracy
- cosine_similarity
- binary_crossentropy
- categorical_crossentropy
- categorical_hinge
- hinge
- squared_hinge
- kullback_leibler_divergence
- logcosh
- mean_absolute_error
- mean_absolute_percentage_error
- mean_squared_error
- mean_squared_logarithmic_error
- poisson
- sparse_categorical_crossentropy

Possible abbreviations:

- acc = ACC = accuracy
- bce = BCE = binary_crossentropy
- mse = MSE = mean_squared_error
- mae = MAE = mean_absolute_error
- mape = MAPE = mean_absolute_percentage_error
- msle = MSLE = mean_squared_logarithmic_error
- log_cosh = logcosh
- cosine_proximity = cosine_similarity

any others will need to be added as custom objects, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68924248/1812732)

Answer (score 1):

There are also metrics available which can't be passed as string. See https://keras.io/api/metrics/ for available metrics.
For example, "root_mean_squared_error", is a metric name but this string won't work, as it is not in the list mentioned in the previous answer.
This should be passed as follows (assuming that keras has been imported):

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse', metrics=[keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
```